# Detecting height of viewing area using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, height

I want to detect the height of the viewable area using Javascript. I have this DIV of height 550px which I want to display on the browser. However, this height might cause the vertical scrollbar to appear on some browsers (depending on how many toolbars the user has installed). In that case I want to detect that, and alert the user about it.

I tried using `document.body.clientHeight` but it doesnt seem to work... gives me the same height when I tried adding new toolbars and refreshed the page.

Answer (score 6):

this should help you:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Comment: +1 for a not in-library solution. We cannot load a full library of +-1000 lines just to avoid to write 5 or 6 more.

Answer (score 5):

Extremely easy in jQuery (and works well across different platforms):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Heyo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert($(window).height());
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height)

Comment: -1: That is just the height of the whole content, not the window height. (eg. My content is 1450px high but my window is only 641px. $(window).height() returns 1450.)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with YUI as well.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Heya</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.0.0b1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
      alert(Y.get(document).get('winHeight'));
    });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Documentation here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/node/)